# Wrong SSL certificate is returned for an Azure website

Tags: azure, ssl, certificate

We have two websites in Azure under different subscriptions which use the same UCC SSL certificate. Everything had been good for a long time until a week or two ago we noticed that one of the sites does not really have our certificate (although it was configured in Azure successfully). When browsing to it using "https" we can see that "https" becomes red, and if we click on it it says: "Server's certificate does not match the URL". The detailed information about the certificate says that it was issued to "*.azurewebsites.net", not to our domain. So seems like the default Azure certificate is used instead of ours.

At the same time our second website works perfect with "https", and the certificate shown is correct. I re-installed the certificate to both sites and re-created SSL bindings using SNI SSL, but it still works only for one of them.

Any ideas on what can cause this?

Comment: This is happening to us too - please let us know if you figure out why. I've also tried setting the dns bindings again and it didn't help.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Our problem has been solved. See the answer below.

Comment: heh, that's my boss, we talked to Microsoft :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Azure website configuration switch from SNI SSL to IP Based SSL.

Once you do that you should have a Virtual IP Address that can be found in the Dashboard tab of the Website on the Azure portal.

In your web hosting provider make sure the www and @ records point to the **Virtual IP Address** instead of pointing to your xxx.azurewebsites.net URL.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has solved the issue. The only thing I don't understand is why one of these records pointed to the wrong IP address (the second one really pointed to xxx.azurewebsites.net). It looks like the IP address changed a little while ago.